# Different output from json_decode on different servers

Tags: json, unicode

I am currently hosting a PHP Facebook app on Heroku, in which I use cURL to obtain data about users from the Graph API.

I am having problems where the data returned contains unicode characters, in that json_decode on the Heroku system isn't outputting the unicode characters correctly. The output on my local system (identical code) is fine.

Looking at the raw JSON returned from Graph, I can see that it contains unicode escapes eg

```
{"id":"100003517896374","name":"Sky\u00e9     Mont\u00e1na","first_name":"Sky\u00e9","last_name":"Mont\u00e1na","link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/skye.montana.73","username":"skye.montana.73","gender":"female","locale":"en_US"}
```

On my local system, json_decode converts this to the following object:

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 100003517896374 [name] => Skyé Montána [first_name] => Skyé [last_name] => Montána [link] => http://www.facebook.com/skye.montana.73 [username] => skye.montana.73 [gender] => female [locale] => en_US )
```

On the Heroku system it is converted as follows:

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 100003517896374 [name] => SkyÃ© MontÃ¡na [first_name] => SkyÃ© [last_name] => MontÃ¡na [link] => http://www.facebook.com/skye.montana.73 [username] => skye.montana.73 [gender] => female [locale] => en_US )
```

My understanding of json_decode is that it will recognise and correctly interpret unicode. In this case, on Heroku, it appears to be recognising unicode, but not interpreting it correctly.

Is there some PHP setting I need to make to fix this? Is it something to do with magic_quotes perhaps? I've set both servers to have the same magic_quotes option (Off) but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

OK, as usual, 5 mins after posting on SO I find the answer.

Apache has a AddDefaultCharset Directive. This can either be set to Off, where nothing is added to the response header; On, where iso-8859-1 is added to the response header as the content-type; or to a specific character set, where that set is added to the response header as the content-type.

In my local Apache env, I had used AddDefaultCharset to set the default character set to UTF-8, which will override anything set in the meta-tag of your HTML page.

On Heroku, AddDefaultCharset is set to off, which means the charset is always determined by the meta-tag in your HTML page.

My EPIC FAIL was that I had a typo in the meta-tag. This wasn't seen in my local env, as the Apache setting was taking precedence, but was being seen in Heroku, where the content type was dependent on the meta tag setting.

Comment: Yeah, in most situations, if you see `Ã©` (or similar) you have UTF8 bytes being interpreted as ISO-8859-1/Windows-1252 (Wrong header, correct bytes). If you see `�` you have ISO-8859-1/Windows-1252 bytes being interpreted as UTF-8 (Right header, wrong bytes)

Comment: @Garreth I am facing the same problem. I'm sending a JSON encoded binary file content in a post request to server where I'm using json_decode() to decode it and the output contains these junk characters. Can you please tell me how to resolve this? Which headers to set in the POST request to avoid this???